# How do I enable line numbers in Kakoune?

Tags: text-editors, kakoune

How do I make the [Kakoune](http://kakoune.org) text editor display line numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On latest Kakoune versions, you can enable line numbers for every buffers by putting the `number_lines` highlighter inside the global scope, with the following command:

`add-highlighter global number_lines`

If you want more control, another solution is to use a hook to add the `number_lines` highlighter on specific windows, for example if you line numbering only on buffers whose names do not contains `*` (as these are usually internal buffers), you can add a hook that does just that:

`hook global WinCreate ^[^*]+$ %{ add-highlighter window number_lines }`

Comment: This does not work for the version I installed from the official Ubuntu 17.04 repositories. However, it works if you compile kakoune from source.

Comment: It looks like my version is just too old. `addhl number_lines` works for my version.

Comment: As of 2018 (Kakoune v2018.10.27), I had to type `add-highlighter global/ number-lines`

Comment: @Nate You should post answers as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2020-11,

```
Kakoune v2020.09.01
```

the following is working:

```
add-highlighter global/ number-lines
```

Make sure you're typing spaces exactly as in the snippet above.

Originally provided by [Nate](https://superuser.com/users/89857/nate) on Dec 7 '18 at 18:59 for Kakoune v2018.10.27.

Comment: Thanks, finally working :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answers for **absolute** line numbers:
`add-highlighter global/ number-lines` or
`hook global WinCreate ^[^*]+$ %{ add-highlighter window/ number-lines }`

---

If you want **relative** line numbers, put into `kakrc`:
`add-highlighter global/ number-lines -relative` or
`hook global WinCreate ^[^*]+$ %{ add-highlighter window/ number-lines -relative }`

---

And if you want **absolute** line numbers with **on-demand relative** line numbers:

```
add-highlighter global/ number-lines
def switch-number-line -params .. %{
    try %{ remove-highlighter window/number-lines }
    add-highlighter window/number-lines number-lines %arg{@}
}
hook global NormalKey  0   'switch-number-line -relative'
hook global NormalKey \D.* 'switch-number-line'
```

This snippet instructs Kakoune to initially show absolute line numbers,
on pressing `0` switch to relative line numbers,
and on pressing non-digit `\D.*` switch back to absolute line numbers.

Usage e.g. type `03j`/`03k` to see relative numbers and go 3 lines down/up.
Type `03C`/`03<a-C>` to see relative numbers and 3 times copy main selection to next/previous lines.

Taken from https://discuss.kakoune.com/t/type-0-to-show-relative-line-numbers-for-the-next-command/760/6
(also look that discussion for a partial solution for issue with **git diff** and **linters** indicators)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Marek Kowalczyk's wonderful answer, if you want to enable line numbers everytime you launch kakoune, I find that going into your .bashrc and entering:

`alias kak="kak -e 'add-highlighter global/ number-lines'"`

helps a lot in getting line numbers everytime you go into a file with kakoune. Not only that, but with this method you have immediate access to disabling this command and tweaking it however you desire.

`man kak`

if you want to learn more about this command.

Comment: Better just to put `add-highlighter global/ number-lines` in your kakrc, surely.